# pvs + how to get the values of pfree in Giga for specific Volume group

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm, volume

in my rhel 7.6 machine I used the pvs command in order to display the Pfree values

```
pvs
  PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize       PFree
  /dev/sda2  rhel_rhel7 lvm2 a--   <39.00g     4.00m
  /dev/sdc   vg_fg   lvm2 a--      <200.00g    0
  /dev/sdd   docker      lvm2 a--  <110.00g    0
```

more correctly way to display only the `Pfree` in `GIGA` is like this

```
pvs -o pv_free --unit=g --no-suffix --no-heading
   0.00
      0
      0
```

since we have different VG then we get 3 values on `Pfree`

any advice how to get the `Pfree` values on GIGA for specific `VG`?

for example lets say we want only the `Pfree` value of  `rhel_rhel7` Volume Group

so expected results should be

```
 pvs ..........................
 0.00
```

Comment: That's what `sed` is for. Or `awk`. Even `cut` might cut it (with a little help from `grep` and perhaps `tr`). I don't see an option built into `pvs` that filters the PV list by VG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--select` to filter `pvs` output. In this case `--select vgname=<name>` will do the trick:

```
# pvs --select vgname=test -o pv_free --unit=g --no-suffix --no-heading
   0.07
```

(I also have 3 VGs and `test` has only one PV with 70 MiB of free space.)

Check `pvs --select help` for more options.

Comment: I obviously checked an outdated version of the manual page, which didn't have the `select` option.

Comment: I didn't know about `select` either, nice finding.